# How to query expanded json content in db2

Tags: json, db2

Since version 11, DB2 supports json functions and json value query. I was trying to follow the documentation but could not figure out how to expand a json object into multiple rows. Would like to know if it's possible at all in DB2.

Example:
The JSON object looks like this:

```
{
 "content":{
   "key_1": {
     "text": "sample",
     "label": "l1"
   },
   "key_2": {
     "text": "sample2",
     "label": "l2"
   },
   ...
 }
}
```

and the table looks like this:

|id|json|
|--|----|
|1 | '{...}'|
|2 | '{...}'|

I want to query this table:
|id|text|label|
|--|----|-----|
|1 |sample|l1|
|1 |sample2|l2|
...

I tried

```
SELECT JSON_VALUE(json, 'strict $.content.*.text' RETURNING CHAR(10)) AS text,
  JSON_VALUE(json, 'strict $.content.*.label' RETURNING CHAR(10)) AS label
FROM table
```

but I got NULL for all the rows.

Any insights are appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I belive you need to do something like this

```
SELECT I, T.*
FROM
    TABLE(VALUES('{
 "content":{
   "key_1": {
     "text": "sample",
     "label": "l1"
   },
   "key_2": {
     "text": "sample2",
     "label": "l2"
   }
 }
}')) AS D(JSON)
,   TABLE(VALUES(1),(2),(3)) AS A(I)
,   JSON_TABLE(D.JSON, 'strict $'
COLUMNS( 
    TEXT    VARCHAR(80) PATH '$.content.key_' || i || '.text'
,   LABEL   VARCHAR(80) PATH '$.content.key_' || i || '.label'
)
    ERROR ON ERROR) AS T
WHERE T.TEXT is NOT NULL
```

which will give you

```
I|TEXT   |LABEL 
-|-------|------
1|sample |l1    
2|sample2|l2
```

The `A` table in the above will need as many rows as you have `key_` entries in the JSON